# Instance of Ford Fulkerson violating property

Tags: algorithm, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

Somehow I created this graph which seems to violate one of the properties that the value of flow is upper bounded by the capacity of min cut.
Here's the graph:

[image]

Max flow that the algorithm finds is 7. (sending 3 on s-a-c-t, 3 on s-b-t and 1 on s-a-t)
While the min-cut in the graph is {s,b} , {a,c,t} with capacity 5.
I'm not sure where I'm going wrong in this. Can someone please correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of a cut is the sum of the capacities of the edges that are "cut".

In the case with cutting the graph into `{s,b}` and `{a,c,t}`, the edges are `s-a`, `b-t`, (and you can count `a-b` if you want), which means the value is 8 (11 if you count `a-b`), not 5.

As far as I can tell, the min cut would include the edges `a-t`, `b-t`, and `c-t`, which has a value of 7, which is consistent with Ford-Fulkerson.

Comment: Oh! I counted incoming edges as well in the capacity of the cut. Thanks a lot!